# Construct Network Topology

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, networking, topology

We are trying to develop a Topology Map of available devices in a network.

I have the details of the system, like IP, Device Name.

All I need to do is to populate them on the graph and show it graphically, the problem is that we need to do it in JSP.

Is there another way, like show using Flex, where I would pass IP/Device Name and just create the environment. BTW its not fixed on how many systems, so its gotta be dynamic.

Can someone help?

Comment: JSP is just a display template technology, it has nothing to do with the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Do you realize that this only returns the devices as known at the server side and NOT at the client side?

Comment: BalusC, yes, I'm aware of that and that's exactly what I need to do.

Comment: This may be better asked on serverfault.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this isn't necessarily a JSP problem. Obtaining list of network devices isn't to be done in a JSP file, but in a real Java class. JSP is just a view technology.

Back to the actual problem, to start you can use the [java.net.NetworkInterface](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html) API for this.

First create a Servlet which obtains a `List` of `NetworkInterface`s in the `doGet()` method, puts it in the request scope and forwards the request to a JSP. As `NetworkInterface` class already conforms the Javabean spec with several useful getter methods, we don't need to wrap it in another Javabean class and can just reuse it.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        List<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        request.setAttribute("networkInterfaces", networkInterfaces);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        throw new ServletException("Cannot obtain networkinterfaces.", e);
    }
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/networkinterfaces.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Map this servlet in `web.xml` on an `url-pattern` of for example `/networkinterfaces`. This servlet would be accessible by `http://example.com/context/networkinterfaces`.

Now create a JSP file `networkinterfaces.jsp` which you place in `WEB-INF` to prevent from direct access by `http://example.com/context/networkinterfaces.jsp` (so that users are forced to use the servlet). Use the [JSTL](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) (just put JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib` if not done yet) [c:forEach](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) tag to iterate over the `List` and access the getters by [EL](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html).

```
<c:forEach items="${networkInterfaces}" var="networkInterface">
    Name: ${networkInterface.name}<br>
    Display name: ${networkInterface.displayName}<br>
    MTU: ${networkInterface.MTU}<br>
    <c:forEach items="${networkInterface.interfaceAddresses}" var="interfaceAddress" varStatus="loop">
        IP address #${loop.index + 1}: ${interfaceAddress.address}<br>
    </c:forEach>
    <hr>
</c:forEach>
```

That should be it.

**Edit** to have it "visually presented", either use Java 2D API to generate an image or use HTML/CSS to position the elements based on the information gathered in servlet.

Comment: The code that you have posted would just help me list the network elements, but I need to show them in a Visual format, that the problem all abt :)

Comment: Either use Java 2D API to creat a png/gif or play smart with the information and a shot of right HTML elements and CSS styles.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a reasonably up to date (albeit horribly slow) option you could launch a series of tracert instances, get the output and parse the IP hops? Then you could use the results to link/add nodes in a tree structure using a graphing API.

This would be a time consuming processes however. I'm sure theres a better way, but this might get you thinking of options.

Comment: Mr. Graves, I have all the data I need, but displaying in a tree structure may not be an option.